# English References in mainly Persian Document (XeLateX, BibTeX)?

Tags: xetex, bibtex, mactex, texworks

I am compiling my document in Persian using XeLaTeX, but the references are all in English and I'm appending them using BibTeX. At the end of the document, the references are all unknown characters, how could I handle this problem?

Comment: That problem solved by using \lr{} tag in the .bib file. But the other problem with it is the formatting which is not ok :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Moh did you solve your problem?